# django web server chat

Tags: django, chat

can any body suggest me an idea about how can
 i create a chat interface between the friend 
list which i have created for my application.

actually a want to create a chat server. i have 
a friends list in my django model. if more then one 
person is online at the same time then they chat with 
one another. for this purpose do i have to create a socket 
or is there any other way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple pluggable apps for using Django as a chat server that you could use or at least use as a reference or starting point.

- django-chat: http://code.google.com/p/django-chat/
- django-jqchat: http://code.google.com/p/django-jqchat/

There are also these posts on using Django with Orbited to create a chat server.

- http://ajaxian.com/archives/django-and-comet
- http://darkporter.com/blog_files/4.django_orbited.html

Comment: Thanks for the jqchat suggestion.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A basic messaging service is fairly easy.  Most of it will be through Javascript/AJAX.  Simply store messages from users to users in the database, and have your AJAX poll the server for updates.  Once the conversation is ended, delete them.

Comment: can i have a tutorial, about how to create Javascript and Ajax for this purpose or any useful link 
thanks

Comment: Can you refer any tutorial for the basic messaging service or any link @Jack M.