# Django-SocketIO: Key Error at /socket.io/xhr-polling//<my-id>

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-socketio

I have setup an example project for django-socketio from https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio. My project is running at port 8001 and socketio server is running at port 8002. But its showing a KeyError for 'socketio' in below section:

At django_socketio/views.py:

```
 socket = SocketIOChannelProxy(request.environ["socketio"])
```

Comment: What's your django version?

Comment: @yuvi: I am using Django 1.5.5

Comment: @yuvi: I had tried it with Django 1.4 but still the problem exists.

Comment: Yeah I deleted that comment. Sorry, I realized it probably doesn't matter in this case...

Comment: Yeah it doesnt matter. So whether there exists any alternatives to make a django app with realtime features ?

Comment: You're talking about [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), and you're [hardly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310706/django-comet-push-least-of-all-evils) [the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730841/django-and-comet) [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117788/comet-framework-for-django?rq=1) [about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698909/django-web-server-chat/2700700#2700700)